# Read the error output of the sed command in shell script

Tags: sed

In case the sed command below fails I want the reason of its failure i.e. error output should also be added as part of the email. How it can be done?

Code is :

```
sed -e  abc.txt > /net/abc.com/test/abc.txt

#Sending email

if [ -f /net/abc.com/test/abc.txt ]; then
       echo "content of abc.txt saved to server" | mail -s "Content of abc" dave@klm.com
else
       echo "File does not exist"
fi
```

After "File does not exist" reason of the failure of sed should be appended.

Comment: The sed command will always fail because missed the actions

Answer (score 3):

The `sed` command sends its errors to (surprisingly enough) standard error. So you can catch it and treat it specially, as per the following transcript:

```
pax> echo hello | sed 's/missing/terminator' >outfile 2>errfile

pax> cat outfile

pax> cat errfile
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unterminated `s' command
```